# A six sided dice is thrown twice

Tags: probability

What (6-sided) dice is thrown twice, what is the probability of two different numbers occurring?

The way I've done it
\begin{align}
P(\text{first_dice}) &= 1/6\\
P(\text{not first_dice}) &= 5/6\\
1/6 \cdot 5/6
\end{align}
Is this right? 
I'm new to this so sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Just count them. There are $36$ options, out of which, in $6$ options you get two identical numbers. So in the other $30$ options you get two different numbers, hence the probability is $\frac{30}{36}$. By the way, the error in your solution is that there is no such thing as $P(\text{first die})$ and $P(\text{not first die})$, but simply $P(\text{second die}\neq\text{first die})$. So instead of the counting solution that I suggested, you can simply throw the first die, and then ask yourself what is the probability that the second die will not land on the same number (the answer is $\frac56$).

Answer (score 1):

That's only correct for a specific value of the first die. The wording can confuse you.

Instead, think of the probability that the second throw is different than the first.

Regardless of how the first die throw lands, there are $5$ possibilities available for the second die throw to be different.

Alternatively, compute $P(D1 = x)P(D2 \neq x)$ for every value of $x$, add them, and you'll get $6$ times what you came up with.

So in other words,

"There is a $\frac16$ probability that the first throw is a 1, and a $\frac56$ probability that the second throw is not. There is a $\frac16$ probability that the first throw is a 2, and a $\frac56$ probability that the second throw is not." And so forth.

Answer (score 0):

You throw the dice for the first time and it lands on $x$.

Now you throw it again, what is the chance that the dice does not land on $x$ again?